# Windows Phone 8 durable In-App purchase and multiple phones?

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

If a user makes an in-app purchase (durable product) on an app and then changes her phone, is the purchase still available for her when she launches the same app on her new phone?

In other words, are the products licensed by phone or by user's Microsoft Account? If by the account, does the CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses automatically contain the product on her new phone or does she have to go through the purchase screen (RequestProductPurchaseAsync) to reactivate the product?

Comment: The license is tied to the user. So as long as he uses the same live account for his new phone, his purchases are carried along. However, I don't know if he has to go through the purchase screen to reactivate the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kookiz said purchase is tied to the user level than device. End user experience is varies on new phone based on your implementation/license querying to unlock the items.

I saw few apps, where the license check is not happened until the purchase experience window is triggered. Probably, developer is not checking the durable IAP license every time - probably saving the IAP purchase state in IsoStore etc.